# How to pass functions to the `evaluate` function from Node Horseman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

With Node Horseman we can use PhantomJS inside of Node. If we want to execute one piece of JS code on the context of a page we do as follows:

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman.open(pageUrl)
        .status()
        .evaluate(function () {
            // Js Code goes here
        })
        .close();
```

Now, suppose that we want to pass something "from the outside" to the evaluate function. For example, if I do the following

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman();

function someFunction() {}

horseman.open(pageUrl)
        .status()
        .evaluate(function () {
            someFunction();
        })
        .close();
```

When I call `someFunction` inside the evaluate it is not found.

Another example, suppose I do the following

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var url = require('url');
var horseman = new Horseman();

horseman.open(pageUrl)
        .status()
        .evaluate(function () {
            // try to use url somehow here
        })
        .close();
```

It also doesn't recognize the `url` object there. I do understand the problem, that code is ran on the context of the page. But is there some way to pass those things from outside, so that we can use them inside of the evaluate?

Answer (score 0):

Your are right about the code beeing ran on the context of the page. You can think of it as if you open your browser's console and paste there everything that goes inside evalute function.

If you paste *someFunction()* into the console, JS runtime will throw an error: *someFunction is not defined*. That is because it was never defined on the context of the page.

There is actually a workaround for passing a function from outside, but it will only work if the function is not dependent on the other functions and Global objects on the Node's context.

Here is an example:

```
function someFunction() {
    return document.title;
}

horseman.open('http://google.com')
    .evaluate(function (someFunction) {
        eval('var sf = ' + someFunction);
        return sf();
    }, someFunction.toString())
    .log() //Will print out "Google"
    .close();
```

url is actually a node.js module. You can try substitute it with any similar client side JS library, and then inject it with one of the following commands:

```
horseman
    .injectJs(file)
```

or

```
horseman
    .includeJs(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
.evaluate(fn, [arg1, arg2,...])
```

Comment: That's very vague. Please show how this can be applied in the question's code.